# NSUserDefaults not saving even after synchronize

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsuserdefaults

I am trying to save my version number from a remote server, and save it for later use. Every time I relaunch the app from XCode on both a device and the simulator, it reports the value as (null). I know for a fact that the server is sending back the data correctly, cause I have it report in NSLog right before I save it.

```
    NSLog(@"local version: %@",[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"version"]);
    if (![[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"version"]) {
        NSString* verNum=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld",(long)[[responseObject objectForKey:@"version"] integerValue]];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:verNum forKey:@"version"];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
        newMode=1;
    }
```

Comment: Split the code up. Assign values to intermediate variables so you can more easily read and debug the code.

Comment: In NSLog you have `def` but in the massive setObject statement you have `responseObject`

Comment: I fixed up the code, it wouldnt have made a difference since def was defined a line above: NSUserDefaults* def=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

Comment: This is working for me, but I don't know exactly what the version format is. Try printing the contents of `responseObject` via `NSLog` to check its contents, and at least provide it here.